# Website doesn't start with default page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have a compiled website that works perfectly on my IIS 7 box.  When I pass the same exact website to a customer, and bring up the site in IIS, the site starts with the registration.aspx instead of default.aspx.  I checked setting and everything seems right but can not figure this out.

Thanks for the input

Comment: What is on your Project Properties > Web tab?

Comment: agree. dbl-check properties and startup.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Have you tried this?]

Have you tried adding Default.aspx to Default document in IIS? Registration.aspx may be set as 'starting page' in visual studio.